# How do I direct all accesses to global memory in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I want all accesses from my program to access global memory (even if the data is found in the L1/L2 cache). To this effect I found out that L1 cache can be skipped by passing these options to nvcc compiler:

```
-Xptxas -dlcm=cg
```

CUDA documentation states this:

```
.cv Cache as volatile (consider cached system memory lines stale, fetch again).
```

So, I am assuming when I run with either -dlcm=cg or -dlcm=cv, the PTX file generated should be different from the one that is generated normally. (The loads should be appended with either .cg or .cv)

My sample program:

```
__global__ void rh_kernel(int *datainRowX, int *datainRowY) {
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (tid != 0)
        return;
    int i, x, y;
    x = datainRowX[1];
    y = datainRowY[2];
    datainRowX[0] = x + y;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int* d_datainRowX;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_datainRowX, sizeof(int) * 268435456);

    int* d_datainRowY;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_datainRowY, sizeof(int) * 268435456);

    rh_kernel<<<1024, 1>>>(d_datainRowX, d_datainRowY);
    cudaFree(d_datainRowX); cudaFree(d_datainRowY);
    return(0);
}
```

I notice that whatever options I pass to the nvcc compiler ("-Xptxas -dlcm=cg" or "-Xptxas -dlcm=cv" or nothing), in all the three cases the PTX generated is the same. I am using -ptx option to generate the PTX file.
What am I missing? Is there any other way to achieve what I am doing?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What GPU are you using (which cc) ?

Comment: I am using Tesla K40

Comment: And nvcc version 6.5.12

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cuda Toolkit Documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/#axzz4VuiywRmI):

> L1 caching in Kepler GPUs is reserved only for local memory accesses,
>   such as register spills and stack data. Global loads are cached in L2
>   only (or in the Read-Only Data Cache).
>
> GK110B-based products such as the Tesla K40 GPU Accelerator, GK20A,
>   and GK210 retain this behavior by default

L1 cache is not used in global memory reads on Kepler by default . Thus - there is no difference in PTX  when you add `-Xptxas -dlcm=cg`.

Disabling L2 cache is not possbile.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Why isn't there a difference when I use             

    -Xptxas -dlcm=cv

Isn't this used to directly access global memory?

Comment: .cv Cache as volatile (consider cached system memory lines stale, fetch again).

Comment: edit: I am ok with not disabling the L2, as long as all accesses also go to the global memory. So, I was wondering if I can use .cv

Comment: From the manual:

_The ld.cv load operation applied to a global System Memory address invalidates (discards) a matching L2 line and re-fetches the line on each new load._

So, if I modify the PTX (inline modifiers?),to convert the ld to ld.cv, then all loads will _always_ go the global memory?
Am I missing something? Thank you for your time.